# Select overlapping holidays per department

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm trying to check if any of the employees at my company are requesting overlapping holidays. It's the policy that only 1 person per department is allowed to be off at once.

What query should I use? (I am a noob, so tell me if you need more information).

An Example of the table I want to use:

```
Request ID      Employee ID      Department ID      Start Date      End Date
1                  10                  1            2015-12-20      2016-12-27
2                  10                  1            2016-06-01      2015-06-14
3                  11                  1            2015-12-26      2015-12-27
4                  11                  1            2016-06-09      2016-06-23
5                  12                  2            2015-12-26      2015-12-26
6                  12                  2            2016-07-01      2016-07-14
```

Results:

```
Request ID            Status
1                  Not Approved, overlapping 26-27/12
2                  Not Approved, overlapping 09-14/06
3                  Not Approved, overlapping completely
4                  Not Approved, overlapping 09-14/06
5                  Approved, not overlapping in this department
6                  Approved, not overlapping in this department
```

In the second phase, I want to compare if the holidays requested, are within a week, containing a bank holiday (I will have a different table with the bank holidays).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Too many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes do date/time...)

Answer (score 1):

One way is with `exists`:

```
select e.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from example e2
                          where e2.departmentid = e.departmentid and
                                e2.employeeid <> e.employeeid and
                                e2.startdate <= e.enddate and
                                e2.enddate >= e.startdate
                         )
             then 'Overlapping'
             else 'NotOverlapping'
        end) as Status
from example e;
```

Getting your full message is trickier and depends on the database.  The problem are multiple overlaps.

Actually, we can get more information without too much problem:

```
select e.RequestId,
       (case when count(e2.RequestId) = 0
             then 'Approved, not overlapping in this department'
             when count(e2.RequestId) = 1
             then (case when min(e2.startdate) <= e.startdate and
                             max(e2.enddate) >= e.enddate
                        then 'Not Approved, overlapping completely'
                        else 'Not Approved, overlapping partially'
                   end)
             else 'Not Approved, multiple overlaps'
        end) as Status
from example e left join
     example e2
     on e2.departmentid = e.departmentid and
        e2.startdate <= e.enddate and
        e2.enddate >= e.startdate and
        e2.employeeid <> e.employeeid
group by e.RequestId, e.startdate, e.enddate;
```

Getting the actual dates is trickier, without knowing the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #holidays(RequestID int, EmployeeID int, DepartmentID int, StartDate date, EndDate date)
insert into #holidays
select 1, 10, 1, '2015-12-20', '2016-12-27'
union select 2, 10, 1, '2016-06-01', '2015-06-14'
union select 3, 11, 1, '2015-12-26', '2015-12-27'
union select 4, 11, 1, '2016-06-09', '2016-06-23'
union select 5, 12, 2, '2015-12-26', '2015-12-26'
union select 6, 12, 2, '2016-07-01', '2016-07-14'


with CTE
as (
    select T1.RequestID,max(T2.RequestID) as T2RequestID, count(*) as cnt
    from #holidays T1
    join #holidays T2 on 
        T1.DepartmentID = T2.DepartmentID 
        and T1.StartDate < T2.EndDate and T1.EndDate  > T2.StartDate
        and T1.RequestID <> T2.RequestID
    group by T1.RequestID
)
select H.*, 
    case 
        when isnull(CTE.cnt,0) = 0 then 'Approved, not overlapping in this department'
        else 'Not Approved, overlapping ' + convert(nvarchar(50),H2.StartDate) + ' - ' + convert(nvarchar(50),H2.EndDate)
    end as Res
from #holidays H
left join CTE on H.RequestID = CTE.RequestID
left join #holidays H2 on H2.RequestID = CTE.T2RequestID
```

Btw, first employer have too big holidays - more than 1 year long :)
Another StartDate > EndDate (what is it ?)

Result 
[image]

Comment: Hahaha, yes, that employee must be the boss! :)

Comment: :) Boss will on holiday one year. And Boss create rule "only 1 person per department is allowed to be off at once"
... And It wil be ME